# Regex replacement on final endings of words

Tags: replace

I would like to replace the final `ly`, `ily`,  `ley` of words with the letter `l`.

So that I get the following changes to words

```
nearly  changed to  nearl
family  changed to  faml
valley  changed to  vall
```

Comment: The description does not agree with the examples.

Comment: Sounds par for the course, but seems to have been fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regexp matching "ly, ily, ley at the end of words" is:

```
\(ly\|ily\|ley\)\>
```

You can use that with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `query-replace-regexp` (for instance), replacing with `l`.

Comment: Based on your suggestion I have used `(insert (replace-regexp-in-string "\\(ly\\|ily\\|ley\\)\\>" "l" word))`.  Why have you defined it that way?  Have seen that a single `\` is usually escaped.

Comment: Why have I "defined" what in which way?  And a single what?

Comment: I'm going to assume you're asking about backslashes.  Your regexp and my regexp are the same -- your double-quoted syntax produces that exact string.

Comment: Yes, about the backslashes.  Your regex is correct, but had to escape them.

Comment: Yes, if you wrote `"\(ly\|ily\|ley\)\>"` in elisp code, that would be the string `(ly|ily|ley)>` which would be a very different regexp.