# Omit the beginning of words

Tags: replace

I want to omit the beginning of words starting with `some` (i.e. `something` is changed to `thing`) using the expression

```
(insert (replace-regexp-in-string "\\<\\some\\" "" word))
```

But I am getting a lisp error on my `regex`.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-regexp "Trailing backslash")
  string-match("\\<\\some\\" #("something" 0 9 (fontified t)) 0)
  replace-regexp-in-string("\\<\\some\\" "" #("something" 0 9 (fontified t)))
  (insert (replace-regexp-in-string "\\<\\some\\" "" word))
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is the way to remove `some` from the beginning of a word, with `(replace-regexp-in-string "\\<\\(some\\)" "" word)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```lisp
(replace-regexp-in-string "\\<\\(some\\)." "" "something" nil nil 1) ; => "thing"
```

---

Some unsolicited advice:

You really should try harder to make your questions clearer.  For example, your question (apparently) has nothing to do with inserting or `insert`.  You should remove that part from the question, as it's only noise. Take that out of the equation.

Learn to read the error message and backtrace clearly. It says that the error occurred when `string-match` was called by `replace-regexp-in-string`.

Read the doc for `replace-regexp-in-string` and the Elisp manual about regexps. You must have read the manual a bit, or learned elsewhere (1) that `\<` matches the start of a word and (2) you need to double a backslash in a Lisp string.

But you haven't learned about matching a subexpression (a regexp group). Read the doc string of `replace-regexp-in-string` and study the expression in this answer - see why I created a group and referenced it with argument `1` in the `replace-regexp-in-string` call.

It's clear that you're trying, and learning. But you have trouble expressing your questions clearly. Trying to do that better will, in itself, help you learn. And it will get you more help from others. No one wants to guess what you're really asking or play a 20-questions game to find out. It's up to you to express yourself clearly.

Comment: Agreed.  Personally I have been ignoring your questions (I essentially answered https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/73041 by accident) because it had become rapidly apparent (at least to my mind) that you are throwing almost every single obstacle you encounter to this site and waiting for someone to solve your problems for you (while often requiring them to *guess* what your problem actually is), rather than attempting to figure things out for yourself.  I believe that if you put more effort into learning and understanding, you would find yourself having fewer problems.

Comment: Not to solve my problems, but to learn from them.  Actual elisp implementations often get too complicated to comprehend for those delving beyond relatively simple customisations.