# Replacing single prefix from word

Tags: regular-expressions

I want to omit the beginning of words starting with `some` (e.g. `something` changed to `thing`).

This is the way I am doing it

```
(insert (replace-regexp-in-string "\\<\\(some\\)" "" word))
```

Is this the way to do this?  Can it be simplified?  do I require to have `\\(` and `\\)`?

Comment: If `word` is somehow obtained from the current buffer, then getting it (however you get it), doing the replacement in the string and then inserting the resulting string is *much* slower than doing `replace-regexp` in the buffer directly. I did a simple test with two functions: one that did a `replace-regexp` on the whole buffer and one that got each word, and did the `insert/replace-regexp-in-string` you show above. I then ran the two functions on a file that contained 1000 `something`s: the whole-buffer fimplementation was almost 100 times faster (4 msec vs 370 msec).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Omit the beginning of words](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73042/omit-the-beginning-of-words)

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration on performance.  I do not envisage that doing so on the whole buffer would be frequently preferable.  But would be useful if it used a selected region.

Comment: `replace-regexp` can be limited to a region.

Comment: Shall look at an implementation with `replace-regexp`.